# Snowing effect with CAReplicatorLayer

Tags: ios, ios4, core-animation, careplicatorlayer

I have a single snowflake image that I would like to replicate and create snowfall on the screen. We can set the instanceCount to X to create a large number of snowflakes and we can set the instanceTransform to put each instance some distance from the next.

However I am not clear how to make them fall down. Does anyone understands if this class was intended to be used for something like this and if so how should it be properly done?

Answer (score 3):

You apply the animation to the original sublayer.... all the replicated layers follow the same animation, adjusted by the instanceDelay and instanceTransform properties.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am understanding so for: 1. Create a path for a snowflake falling down 2. CAKeyframeAnimation and provide the path. 3. Create a layer for the snowflake and add the above animation to it 4. Use CAReplicatorLayer to create 300 instances and transform then 10 points along x and y.        This will make them all uniformly distributed. Any idea how to introduce randomness to this? Thank you! Vance

Comment: You can add the randomness when you set up the replicated layers (see your other post I responded to) and I guess you could use an NSTimer that modified/animated the instanceDelay and instanceTransform properties as you went along?

Comment: @adam, Uhm, link please?